# vue-router push do not hide the first page when the data array is big

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When I use `this.$router.push("/history/" + fileid);` from my `Home.vue` to go in the `History.vue`, I'm making in the `created` or `mounted` a `socket.io` request that is containing a lot of data and the rendering with `v-for` takes at least 2/3 sec.

The `Home.vue` do not disappear while the 2/3 sec and then we can see the `History.vue` appear under it time that the data arrived.

Is there a way to make the `Home.vue` disappear directly?

**Edit**: `Ajax` was replaced with `socket.io` during the process.

**Edit2:** In fact "a lot of data" is only 300 elements, the request is really instantly.

My *created* function:

```js
created: function() {
    console.log("------------ HISTORY -----------");
    let state = this.$store.state;
    if (state.socket.io._callbacks["$history"] != undefined) {
        state.socket.io.off("history");
    }
    console.log("Binding history");
    state.socket.io.on("history", data => {
        if (data.success) { //if everything is alright
            //For each item in the data.history I will stock them in a total_history array
            data.history.map(h => {
                h.internalid = internalid++; //key for v-for
                h.histtype = 0;              //history    
                this.total_history.push(h);  //add it to the total array
            });
            //For each item in the data.lock_history I will stock them in the total_history array
            data.lock_history.map(h => {
                h.internalid = internalid++;  //key for v-for
                h.histtype = 1;               //lock
                this.total_history.push(h);   //add it to the total array
            });
            //foreach item (300) I convert the datetime string to a Datetime Object
            this.total_history.map(t => {
                t.datetime = new Date(t.datetime);
            });
        }
    });

    //Send a request to get the function above exec on response from server
    let fileid = this.$route.params.fileid;
    fileid = parseInt(fileid); //get url param
    if (typeof fileid == "number") {
        console.log("get history: " + fileid);
        state.socket.io.emit("history", { //send the request to get history
            user: state.user.name,
            token: state.user.token,
            document_id: fileid
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with adding a hiding class during the leave-active event of a vue transition to my `App.vue`

It looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <transition
    leave-active-class="hide-router"
    >
      <router-view/>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.hide-router
{
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

But it's probably a pretty bad fix. If there someone with another idea?

Answer (score 0):

Brother it take time because you added code after getting response successfully.
if you wanna redirect to History page you can use Navigation guard and handle this from navigation guard functions. please visit vuejs documentation.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand. There is my created function: [here](https://pastebin.com/3CATWy7B).  I think it's not the code but the rendering that takes time. I do not have a problem if there are fewer data. In fact its only 300 items in the array.